# How to add blank rows to a stored procedure if the row count is not divisible by 15

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that I would like to output a row count that is divisible by 15. For example, I have this stored procedure that outputs 33 rows but each page holds exactly 15 rows. On the last page that only has 3 rows, the spacing is messed up. Because the row count is always dynamic, I thought it would be easier to make the row count a number that is divisible by 15. So in this case, it would add 12 blank rows to keep the spacing correct.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY YEAR(rce.Ecodate) ) AS Row ,
        rce.ReportRunCaseId AS CaseId ,
        YEAR(rce.EcoDate) AS EcoYear ,
        SUM(rce.NetInv) AS NetInvSum ,
        SUM(rce.NDCash) AS NDCashSum ,
        SUM(rce.DiscCash) AS DiscCashSum ,
        SUM(rce.GrossGas) AS GrossGasSum ,
        SUM(rce.GrossOil) AS GrossOilSum ,
        SUM(rce.NetProdTax) AS NetProdTaxSum ,
        SUM(rce.NetOpCost) AS NetOpCostSum ,
        SUM(rce.WellCost) AS WellCostSum ,
        SUM(rce.NetOil) AS NetOilSum ,
        SUM(rce.CoNetRevOil) AS CoNetRevOilSum ,
        SUM(rce.CoNetRevGas) AS CoNetRevGasSum ,
        SUM(rce.NetGas) AS NetGasSum ,
        rce.WellCount ,
        rcl.SortId
FROM    PhdRpt.ReportCaseList AS rcl
        INNER JOIN PhdRpt.RptCaseEco AS rce ON rce.ReportId = rcl.ReportId
                                               AND rce.ReportRunCaseId = rcl.ReportRunCaseId
GROUP BY rcl.SortId ,
        rce.ReportId ,
        rce.ReportRunCaseId ,
        YEAR(rce.EcoDate) ,
        rce.WellCount
```

I have read that I can use INSERT INTO to add rows to the table. Should I use something like this:

```
INSERT  INTO rce
        SELECT  num - 1
        FROM    T1
        WHERE   ( num % 15 ) = 0
```

Comment: Using the database to help align a ui component is generally a bad idea, because of its fragility and cost of maintenance.

Comment: @StingyJack The spacing is already there for the previous pages. It is only the last page that needs to be fixed. If there were 15n rows, the spacing would be correct.

Comment: I know what you mean. The problem I am talking about is that you are using a stored procedure to help with display formatting. This model does not usually provide enough separation of the concerns, and can break easily or require a lot of time to add new features or change existing ones. Consider using a different tool instead of SQL to format the data for display (if you can, some situations dont allow it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Insert the records you are selecting in the example into a temp
  table.
- Then issue another insert into the temp table for the blank
  rows that you want to add.
- Then select the records from the temp
  table as the return value for the stored proc.